# Sawtooth-supply-chain /bin/sh: 1: bin/splice_json: Permission denied

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-sawtooth

I am trying to run sawtooth-supply-chain from my own computer to get a better understanding of the environment. However, I've run into an issue after running

```
    docker-compose up

    git clone https://github.com/hyperledger/sawtooth-supply-chain
cd sawtooth-supply-chain
git diff 50c404c >bionic.patch
patch --dry-run -R -p1 <bionic.patch
patch           -R -p1 <bionic.patch
sudo docker-compose up
```

I am now running into an error at step 9/11 which is the splice_JSON file build

```
    Step 9/11 : RUN mkdir /node_deps   && bin/splice_json     asset_client/package.json     fish_client/package.json     server/package.json     > /node_deps/package.json   && cd /node_deps && npm install && cd -   && ln -s /node_deps/node_modules asset_client/   && ln -s /node_deps/node_modules fish_client/   && ln -s /node_deps/node_modules server/
 ---> Running in ed3fb485568e
/bin/sh: 1: bin/splice_json: Permission denied
Service 'shell' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c mkdir /node_deps   && bin/splice_json     asset_client/package.json     fish_client/package.json     server/package.json     > /node_deps/package.json   && cd /node_deps && npm install && cd -   && ln -s /node_deps/node_modules asset_client/   && ln -s /node_deps/node_modules fish_client/   && ln -s /node_deps/node_modules server/' returned a non-zero code: 126
```

I tried to do chmod 777 /bin/splice_json and run git bash on elevated

Any assistance is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Running `patch` may have removed executible permission from one or more files under `./bin`.  Before running `docker-compose`, restore execute permission on all `./bin/*` files:

`chmod +x ./bin/*`